# Change the sound in Local notification package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building tasks app and I try to change the sound of notification based on the title of task
For example if the task name is go to gym I want the notification sound go to gym something like that.
I am building an app to blind people and I want to guide them by telling them which task its time come
This is my code to add tasks and my notification service class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/Component/component.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/Cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/Cubit/states.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/Notification/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/sqflite/sqflite-page.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/todo_list/tasks_screen.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:tasks_feature/sqflite/sqflite-page.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:text_to_speech/text_to_speech.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

class AddTasksscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTasksscreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTasksscreen> createState() => _AddTasksscreenState();
}

class _AddTasksscreenState extends State<AddTasksscreen> {
  SqlDb sqlDb = SqlDb();

  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var titleController = TextEditingController();

  late FlutterTts Tts;
  var descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  var dateController = TextEditingController();

  SpeechToText speechToText = SpeechToText();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Tts = FlutterTts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<bookcubit, bookstates>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: InkWell(
                    onDoubleTap: () async {
                      int response = await sqlDb.insertdataToDatabase('''
                            INSERT INTO tasks ( title , description , date )
                            VALUES ("${titleController.text}","${descriptionController.text}","${dateController.text}")
                                 ''');
                      if (response > 0) {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => TasksListScreen()),
                            (route) => false);

                        NotificationService().scheduleNotification(
                            id: bookcubit.get(context).id,
                            title: titleController.text,
                            body: descriptionController.text,
                            DataTime: DateTime.parse(dateController.text));
                        Tts.synthesizeToFile(titleController.text, "Demo.mp3");
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            controller: titleController,
                            onTap: () async {
                              var available = await speechToText.initialize();
                              if (available) {
                                setState(() {
                                  speechToText.listen(
                                    onResult: (result) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        titleController.text =
                                            result.recognizedWords;
                                        bookcubit.get(context).texttovoice(
                                            'إسم المهمة هو ${titleController.text} ');
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return 'title must not be empty';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                              labelText: 'Task Name',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.task),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            controller: descriptionController,
                            onTap: () async {
                              var available = await speechToText.initialize();
                              if (available) {
                                setState(() {
                                  speechToText.listen(
                                    onResult: (result) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        descriptionController.text =
                                            result.recognizedWords;
                                        bookcubit.get(context).texttovoice(
                                            'وصف المهمة هو ${descriptionController.text} ');
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return 'discription must not be empty';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                              labelText: 'Discription Contant',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.task),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                            controller: dateController,
                            readOnly: true,
                            onTap: () async {
                              DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
                                context,
                                showTitleActions: true,
                                minTime: DateTime.now(),
                              ).then((value) {
                                dateController.text =
                                    DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                                        .format(value!);
                                //print(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(value));
                              });
                            },
                            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return 'date must not be empty';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                              labelText: 'Task Date',
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('appicon');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
            importance: Importance.max,
            sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("Demo.mp3")),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    SqlDb db = SqlDb();
    await db.deleteDatabase('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = $id');
    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }

  Future scheduleNotification(
      {int? id,
      String? title,
      String? body,
      String? payload,
      required DateTime DataTime}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id!,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          DataTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        await notificationDetails(),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
}
```

I want the notification sound to be based on the task name instead of the default notification sound For example if the task name is go to gym the notification sound be go to gym

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am building this app for the blind, I want to tell them the name of the task whose time is come because the main notification sound will not help them to know which task its time come